# How to use AWS CLI to deploy lambda function to specific alias or version?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

Before I have Lambda version and alias, based on the API [update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) I can successfully deploy by

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file fileb://archive.zip
```

After I added version and alias, I have Lambda version

- **$LATEST** (default)
- **1**
- **2**

and alias

- **staging** (point to version **1**)
- **prod** (point to version **2**)

I try to deploy to **staging** (version **1**),

---

### 1st Try

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789000:function:myFunction:staging --zip-file fileb://archive.zip
```

gave error

> Current operation does not support
>   versions other than $LATEST. Please set the version to $LATEST or do
>   not set a version in your request.

---

### 2nd Try

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file fileb://archive.zip --s3-object-version 1
```

or

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file fileb://archive.zip --s3-object-version staging
```

gave error

> Please do not provide other FunctionCode
>   parameters when providing a ZipFile.

---

How to use AWS CLI to deploy lambda function to specific alias or version correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay so assuming you already managed to deploy your lambda with this command :

```sh
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip
```

And that you have created 2 versions with 2 alias (staging an prod).

Now you just need to publish to the rigth version :

```sh
VERSION=1
aws lambda update-alias --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --name staging --function-version $VERSION
```

```sh
VERSION=2
aws lambda update-alias --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --name prod --function-version $VERSION
```

If you want to go one step further you can bind the last deployment to the latest version. So first you need to retrieve the latest version and for this I use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but feel free to use whatever you want, and then update with this version.

```sh
VERSION=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME | jq -r .Version)
aws lambda update-alias --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --name staging --function-version $VERSION
```

Here is the [update-alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-alias.html) documentation.
And here is the [publish-version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/cli/latest/reference/lambda/publish-version.html) documention.

Comment: **jq** is very helpful! You must read my mind, that is exact question came in my mind - how to get result from command!

Comment: This is a very clean solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

based on AWS documentations

> A published version is immutable. That is, you can't change the code or configuration information.

so you need to publish a new version of your function and then update the alias to point to the newly created version.